# "this" on jquery for each input [text] validate

Tags: jquery, this

I have multiple inputs of text within a form and want to validate each input like this:

```
  $(document).on('keyup', 'input [type="text"]', function (){
    var html = '<span class="error">Se necesita una <b>descripcion mayor a 3 letras!</b>!</span>';
    var val = $(this);
    alert(val.val());   
    //if it's NOT valid  
    if(t.val().length < 4){  
        $(html).insertAfter(val);

    }  
    //if it's valid  
    else{  
        val.find('.error').remove();

    }
});
```

I'm doing a keyup event on each of the inputs and using this to reference the input on which the user is typing into, but no validation occurs and no value is alerted so I guess that the function is not triggering is the input selector right? Is that the correct way to use "this"?

Comment: that keyup on the document isn't the best efficient code ever. try give it a lower element then the document.

Comment: You can find it using `next()` method since it is its sibling, so `val.next().remove()` should work.

Comment: It should work, but that **val name** for `$(this)` instead of `$this`, is another poor thing in that piece of code.

Comment: why is that? I thought that by giving variables to selectors simplified jQuery's work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`input [type="text"]` is not the right selector, it should be `input[type="text"]` or `input:text`

The space is important. It's looking for child elements of `input` elements that have `[type=text]` attributes.

---

You may be better off rewiring your event like so:

```
$("input:text").on("keyup", function(e) {
    var $input = $(this);

    if($input.val().length < 4) {  
        var $error = $("<span>", {
            html = "Se necesita una <b>descripcion mayor a 3 letras!",
            "class" = "error"
        });
        $error.insertAfter($input);
    }
    else {  
        $input.siblings(".error").remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: Your second approach will attach the event handler on all the `input:text` elements. Instead of `document` we can use `form` as root selector and still use `on` method's delegate feature.

Comment: another quick question will the find method work? I want it to find the span thats after the input being changed, or do i need to do something like val.children().remove();?

Comment: @SamuelLopez - no, that find will not work. You'll most likely use `val.siblings('.error')`

Comment: ok thank you very much for you answers with siblings everything worked fine!

Answer (score 2):

You have a space in the selector which is wrong. You can try this which is even better.

```
$(document).on('keyup', 'input:text', function (){
   ....
});
```

Instead of `document` we can use form as root selector to reduce the scope.

```
$('form').on('keyup', 'input:text', function (){
   ....
});
```

If you have a name or id to the form replace the selector accordingly.